# Multi edit object in one query JSONB Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I want to modify color and title with same data for specified items with this keys `{0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d91,0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d92,0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d93}` in one query the result must be like this all in one query
result must be like this

```
{
  "designation": "test"
  "items": {
    "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d90": {
      "id": 71,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "item1",
    }, 
  "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d91": {
      "id": 72,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "item2",
    },
    "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d92": {
      "id": 73,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "item3",
    },
    "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d93": {
      "id": 74,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "item4",
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "designation": "test"
  "items": {
   "items": {
    "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d90": {
      "id": 71,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "item1",
    }, 
  "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d91": {
      "id": 72,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "updated",
    },
    "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d92": {
      "id": 73,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "updated",
    },
    "0024dd81-db96-4a87-863b-e6ca9dd69d93": {
      "id": 74,
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "title": "updated",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the query you tried, please? In what format do you get the input data (ie. which ids to update, which color and which title to set)?

Comment: It's doable. Can you share further info using db fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=bb214abd3fbf23dd40b0d0c2d1cb4fbe So far I tried.